# .NET triggering multiple instances of an R script

Tags: c#, .net, r, rstudio, rscript

In one of my team's projects we trigger an R script using an ASP.NET web service. Here's the code snippet:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This class runs R code from a file using the console.
        /// </summary>
        public class RScriptRunner
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Runs an R script from a file using Rscript.exe.
            /// Example:  
            ///   RScriptRunner.RunFromCmd(curDirectory + @"\ImageClustering.r", "rscript.exe", curDirectory.Replace('\\','/'));
            /// Getting args passed from C# using R:
            ///   args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
            ///   print(args[1]);
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="rCodeFilePath">File where your R code is located.</param>
            /// <param name="rScriptExecutablePath">Usually only requires "rscript.exe"</param>
            /// <param name="args">Multiple R args can be seperated by spaces.</param>
            /// <returns>Returns a string with the R responses.</returns>
            public string RunFromCmd(string rCodeFilePath, string rScriptExecutablePath, string args)
            {
                string file = rCodeFilePath;
                string result = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    info.FileName = rScriptExecutablePath;
                    info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(rScriptExecutablePath);
                    info.Arguments = rCodeFilePath + " " + args;

                    info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    info.UseShellExecute = false;
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

                    using (var proc = new Process())
                    {
                        proc.StartInfo = info;
                        proc.Start();
                        result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("R Script failed: " + result, ex);
                }
            }
        }

        public string TriggerR(int cohortId1, int cohortId2)
        {

            RScriptRunner r = new RScriptRunner();
            var rScriptPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rScriptPath"].ToString();
            var rScriptExePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rScriptExePath"].ToString();

            //r.RunFromCmd("C:\\lisa_test.txt", "C:\\Users\\meppielmr\\Desktop\\R\\R-3.3.1\\bin\\Rscript.exe", cohortId1.ToString() + " " + cohortId2.ToString());
            var result = r.RunFromCmd(rScriptPath, rScriptExePath, cohortId1.ToString() + " " + cohortId2.ToString());

            return result;
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
```

Everything is working as expected, but we need to find a way to run more than one script in parallel.

Using the console and a unit test we executed the R script nearly a dozen times simultaneously. The script never failed, but we noticed that R only processed one script at a time.

Is there a way we can get around this so multiple users using the application at the same time won't have to wait until the other user has finished?

Thanks for all the help and suggestions.